# AWS Amazon Athena impossible to partitioning data with a BOOLEAN field

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-dynamodb, partitioning, amazon-athena

I'm trying to partition my data on Amazon Athena with a boolean field but it doesn't seem to be working.

My data (in JSON) looks like this schema :

```
{
    "name": "apple",
    "size": "L",
    "color": "red",
    "fruit": true
}

or

{
    "name": "brocolis",
    "size": "L",
    "color": "green",
    "fruit": false
}
```

I created the table on Amazon athena as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE fruits (
  name string, 
  color string, 
  size string
)
PARTITIONED BY (fruit boolean)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
LOCATION
  's3://bucket-for-athena-test/'
```

Then I try to create a first partition like this:

```
ALTER TABLE fruits ADD PARTITION (fruit = true) LOCATION 's3://bucket-for-athena-test/fruits/'
```

And I get an error message:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: FI07HJFNAKH3HLUU5DATP2G4LJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG))

This query ran against the "fruits_database" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 3aa0434e-b492-4090-8dd6-24e498a0e1fa.
```

Could somebody please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The partition style used by Athena is derived from Hive style. You cannot create a table with partition column as column from actual data. Rather this partition should be a part of your location for example in your case the s3 path should be some thing like `'s3://bucket-for-athena-test/fruit=mango'` or `'s3://bucket-for-athena-test/fruit=apple'` .

So this path `'s3://bucket-for-athena-test/fruit=mango'` will have the data with all mangoes and `'s3://bucket-for-athena-test/fruit=apple'` will have apples.

When you run a query on top this table applying a filter like `select * from table where fruit = 'mango'` this will only scan mango data and leave other folders untouched.This is the actual benefit of partitioning where it skip scanning unnecessary data.

To read more about partitioning refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html).

So if you want to create partitioned table from normal table then you can use CTAS example as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas-examples.html#ctas-example-partitioned)

```
CREATE TABLE fruits_partitioned 
WITH (
     format = 'TEXTFILE',  
     external_location = 's3://bucket-for-athena-test/', 
     partitioned_by = ARRAY['fruit']) 
AS SELECT column1, column2, column3, fruit
FROM fruit_unpartitioned;
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response. The problem is not that I can't partition. I can do it very well on fruit exactly as you explained. But on the other hand, when it comes to partitioning on a boolean, nothing works anymore.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue when boolean type involved in partition column type https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6590 . I don't think Athena uses Hive 3.0 where this issue is fixed

Comment: I've also seen this issue, I was hoping that the problem didn't come from there, but I'm afraid that's the real problem...

Answer (score 0):

The source error is:

***One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string***

This means that the partition query was attempted on a column (attribute value) that does not exist.

The column name specified in the partition query is **'fruit'**.

However, the column named **'fruit'** is not defined in the table structure. This is the root cause of the error.

**How to fix the problem?**

The fix can be done in 2 ways -

1. Run the partition query on one of the column names that exists in table structure (Example: color)
2. Alter the table structure to include 'fruit' as a column.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the answer. The problem is that I'm partitioning on a boolean field. Indeed, if I perform the same processing but I partition on the size : ```CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE fruits ( name string, color string, fruit boolean ) PARTITIONED BY (size string)``` everything's running smoothly with no problems. In the Athena query language, we do not have to include the partition column in the declared column (docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) or it will throw an error : ```FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10035]: Column repeated in partitioning columns```